# when using Hashmaps, and accessing the value based on key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` which basically tries to store objects based on the name of the object as the key. However, the first time when the object is not yet there in the `HashMap` instead of retuning me a `null` it returns an `object`. As a result, it never goes and creates a new object and never puts it in the `HashMap` - I expect it to return `null`.

This is my code...

```
private static Map<String, SObj> MComponentCache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Sobj>());

    static SObj getSObj(String cName) {
        SObj cmp = null;
        String pKey = "Component:" + cName.intern();
        cmp = MComponentCache.get(cName);
        synchronized (pKey){
            if (cmp == null){
                cmp = new SObj(cName);
                MComponentCache.put(cName, cmp);
            }
        }
        return cmp;
    }
```

Could anyone please help me correct this.

Comment: What does it return you? I don't see how a `HashMap` wouldn't return `null` if it doesn't contain the key; not really how a `HashMap` works.

Comment: Really, it returns an object that you did not put there?  What object?

Comment: Synchronizing on `pKey` does not do what you think it does, because it is not interned. `cName` *is* interned, but that is not the object on which you synchronize.

Comment: write a little test program to make sure you really knows the behavior or HashMap, instead of pumping lots of meaningless code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. Synchronizing on the key is pointless, as it is a newly constructed local object, and a synchronized map isn't atomic between operations. You need to synchronize on the map in a block that includes both the `get()` and the `put()` operations.